# MiniZinc: syntax error: syntax error, unexpected if, expecting end of file

Tags: minizinc

I don't know why my code doesn't work in Minizinc... Can you help me?
This is the error but i think there are another errors:
MiniZinc: syntax error: syntax error, unexpected if, expecting end of file

```
array [1..n, 1..2] of 1..n: cards;

var int: M1;
var int: M2;
var int: m1;

include "globals.mzn";


constraint(M1 < m1);

constraint(M2 > m1);

constraint(M2 - M1 > d); 

constraint alldifferent ( [cards[v,1] | v in 1..n]);

constraint forall(v in 1..M1) if v!=0 then (cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]) endif;
constraint forall(v in M1+1..m1)(cards[v,2] < cards[v-1,2]);
constraint forall(v in m1+1..M2)(cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]);
constraint forall(v in m1+1..n) if v!=n then (cards[v,2] < cards[v-1,2]) endif;

solve satisfy;

output
["Cards (" ++ show(cards[v1,v2]) ++ ")" ++ "/n" | v1 in 1..n, v2 in 1..2];
```

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `forall` is looking for its expression clause, from the [Minizinc documentation](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/spec.html#generator-call-expressions) `<ident-or-quoted-op> "(" <comp-tail> ")" "(" <expr> ")"`, wrap the whole `if` in parenthesis, like this `constraint forall(v in m1+1..n)(if v!=n then (cards[v,2] < cards[v-1,2]) endif);`

Upon fixing that you will find that the model still fails, `MiniZinc: evaluation error: comprehension iterates over an infinite set`, because the variables `M1, m1, M2` have no bounds given by their definitions and their constraints don't restrict the domains, so `M2 > m1 > M1` and `M2 - M1 < d`, gives no upper bound for `M2` or lower for `M1`, and makes Minizinc try all the values in the domain of `int` for one of the variables and test the other with values within a gap of `d` (check [variable-bounds](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/efficient.html#variable-bounds)), try bounding the variables from their definition, something like `var 1..x`, where `x` might be the maximum value any of those variables could take in a solution that still makes sense, from the `forall` definitions it seems like you consider that `m1+1 <= n`, so maybe use `n` as the upper bound.

From `constraint forall(v in 1..M1) if v!=0 then (cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]) endif;` you can eliminate `if v!=0` if `M1 > 0`, because `v` will never take that value, and rightly so, because if `M1 < 0` the model will access out of the bounds of the array (if the model compiles at all), because all the indices of `cards` are positive `[1..n, 1..2]`. And if all of that applies, also `(v in 1..M1)` will make another array access out of bounds when `v=1` at `cards[v-1,2]`, perhaps your model still makes sense to you using `constraint forall(v in 2..M1)(cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]);`

Finally, you have `cards` in an `alldifferent` constraint, but cards is not declared as a variable, if cards really is a decision variable use `array [1..n, 1..2] of var 1..n: cards;`

I tested this modified version of you model and got a feasible solution.

```
int: n = 5;
int: d = 3;
array [1..n, 1..2] of var 1..n: cards;

var 1..n: M1;
var 1..n: M2;
var 1..n: m1;

include "globals.mzn";


constraint(M1 < m1);

constraint(M2 > m1);

constraint(M2 - M1 > d); 

constraint alldifferent ( [cards[v,1] | v in 1..n]);

constraint forall(v in 2..M1)(cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]);
constraint forall(v in M1+1..m1)(cards[v,2] < cards[v-1,2]);
constraint forall(v in m1+1..M2)(cards[v,2] > cards[v-1,2]);
constraint forall(v in m1+1..n)(if v!=n then (cards[v,2] < cards[v-1,2]) endif);

solve satisfy;

output
["Cards (" ++ show(cards[v1,v2]) ++ ")" ++ if v2 != 2 then ", " else "\n" endif | v1 in 1..n, v2 in 1..2];
```

```
Cards (5), Cards (4)
Cards (4), Cards (3)
Cards (3), Cards (2)
Cards (2), Cards (1)
Cards (1), Cards (2)
```